# How to handle alternative backend dependencies in pkg-config?

Tags: pkg-config

I have a library that is split into a front-end and multiple back-ends. Client programs must link against the front-end library, and one back-end library. When pkg-config is called for the front-end, I'd like pkg-config to enforce that some back-end is specified.

Let's call the front-end libfoo-frontend, and the back-ends libfoo-backend-alpha and libfoo-backend-beta.

An obvious solution might seem to be inverting the dependencies- have each back-end have 'Requires: libfoo-frontend'. However, this won't work because pkg-config will then give the libfoo-backend flags *before* the libfoo-frontend flags. I.e., we'll end up with a link command line with "-lfoo-backend-alpha -lfoo-frontend", and the linker won't end up including libfoo-backend-alpha since it doesn't satisfy any unmet dependencies in the preceding objects, and then will later fail when the dependencies in libfoo-frontend are unmet.

My current solution is that the pkg-config specs do not specify and dependency between the front-end and back-ends. It is up to the user to link against both the front-end and some back-end. The downside is that the user must know that this is required, and if they forget to link against a back-end they'll have the link fail with unmet dependencies, which is relatively uninformative.

A solution that I'd hoped for is to have the front-end spec have a line like 'Requires: libfoo-backend', and all of the backend pkg-config specs have a line like 'Provides: libfoo-backend'. The user would then do something like 'pkg-config --libs libfoo-frontend libfoo-backend-beta'. If the user forgets to specify some backend, pkg-config would complain to remind them. Unfortunately, pkg-config does not have such a 'Requires' key-word.